# Magento 2: Get product by custom attribute

Tags: magento-2.1, product

I need to get a product but I only have a custom attribute (EAN), no ID, no SKU.

Is there a way to get a product by custom attribute in M2? The error I get when trying is this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::getEntityPkName()
must be an instance of Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity,
instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Flat given,
called in
vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php
on line 1369
```

and defined in `/home/www/olesiejuk/www/dev.olesiejuk.pl/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php` on line 1532

Thank you!

UPDATE (add code):

```
//[step] get product ID
    $filter = $this->filterFactory->create();

    $filter
        ->setField('ean')
        ->setValue($value)
        ->setConditionType('eq');

    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($filter);

    $productCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();

    $product = $this->product->loadByAttribute('ean', $value);

    $products = $this->productRepository->getList($productCriteria)->getItems();
```

Comment: But why you can't get any id or sku?

Comment: i think you can create a direct sql and searh in DB your for that EAN, and get the id or sku

Comment: I can't get the ID or SKU, because it's a search field where a customer can search using EAN/ I tried using ```loadByAttribute()``` from Product model, but it always return product with ID = 1... Any ideas apart from SQL or getting SKU/ID?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone also running into this error, make sure `used_in_product_listing` is set to `true` for the attribute you're trying to filter on.

Comment: Had the same issue. This fixes the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below class to create object for searchCirteriaBuilder and use your custom attribute as addFilter to fetch the items match the searchcirteria.

```
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository

        $filters[] = $this->filterBuilder
        ->setField('ean')
        ->setConditionType('eq')
        ->setValue($value)
        ->create();

        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters($filters);

        $productCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();

        $products = $this->productRepository->getList($productCriteria);

        $items = $products->getItems();

        foreach($items as $item) {

        $productId = $item->getId();
        $sku = $item->getSku();

        }
```

Comment: Tried exactly that, got the error refferenced above.

Comment: Could share your entire code.

Comment: added in original post

Comment: @MateuszSerotiuk I updated my answer I tried my self the answered code it works fine, i don't face any error message like what you mentioned, could you try the edited answer. Hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your input there! I ended up convincing the client to change business logic instead of coding this one - just a simpler way to do it. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and resolved by using following pattern:

```
$collection
->getSelect()
->joinLeft(
    ['status' => 'catalog_product_entity_varchar'],
    'e.row_id = status.row_id AND status.attribute_id = 202',
    []
)
->where('status.store_id = 1')
->where("status.value ='test'");
```