# magento 2 strange issue

Tags: magento2

Installed extension vsourz-html-sitemap
And executed

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I am getting this strange issue .

```
            Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::getEntityPkName() must be an instance of Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity, instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Flat given, called in /home/pocketgrocery/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php on line 1369 and defined in /home/pocketgrocery/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php:1532 Stack trace: #0 /home/pocketgrocery/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(1369): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection->getEntityPkName(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Flat)) #1 /home/pocketgrocery/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(1476): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->_addAttributeJoin('status', 'inner') #2 /home/pocketgrocery/public_html/vendor/magento/module-c in /home/pocketgrocery/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php on line 1532
```

Even compiled and cleaned the cache.

Comment: run upgrade as `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` not `php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: it display  error if I do not added -dmemory_limit=5G in command.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Magento (2.0 / 2.1)` version and if your extension is compatible with,  this error occurs on the setup:upgrade execution ?

EDIT:

Run these commands on the root :

- 1. php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
- 2. php bin/magento setup:di:compile;
- 3. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- 4. php bin/magento cache:flush

Also make sure of the deploy mode on your production server. If necessary remove `var/generation` and `var/di` (be very carefully with this step).

Comment: Locally I  uploaded the extension in app/code and executed 
Setup:upgrade execution
and it worked as expected but when I uploaded on live server and executed etup:upgrade execution and tried to run the extension and it start throwing the issue.

Comment: It is compatible with magento version

Comment: extension url https://marketplace.magento.com/vsourz-html-sitemap.html#bv_questions

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Done with 4 steps but no luck yet let me delete  var/generation

Comment: after del of generation folder and di folder I followed the above steps and now still same error

Comment: any suggestion or help ?

Comment: Check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181468/magneto-2-get-product-by-custom-attribute/181493 I think you can find some help. Once this error is related on EAV I think you can run again the installation of the module to make sure that the correct install and upgrade scripts makes the necessary changes on tables. You could check your reindex data for flat cases (it's a try...). Remember to check the setup table to make sure of extension version.

Comment: Let me remove and reinstall it again.

Comment: Categories and pages are showing perfectly but when I turned on product it throw errors.